# error happened when use red5-client to connect remote red5 server

Tags: red5

First I use adobe flash player to connect my red5 server(using rtmps protocal) and it success

> rtmps://myred5ServerName:443/live
>
> 15:29:05:203 - NetConnection.Connect.Success

But When I use Red5Client to try to connect it , it failed.
I just used the Example code ClientTest.java

```
public class ClientTest extends RTMPSClient {

private String server = "myred5ServerName";

//private int port = 1935;
//private int port = 5080;
private int port = 443;

//private String application = "oflaDemo";
private String application = "RtmpRelay";

private String filename = "hobbit_vp6.flv";

// live stream (true) or vod stream (false)
private boolean live;

private static boolean finished = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final ClientTest player = new ClientTest();
    // decide whether or not the source is live or vod
    //player.setLive(true);
    // connect
    player.connect();

    synchronized (ClientTest.class) {
        if (!finished) {
            ClientTest.class.wait();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Ended");
}

public void connect() {
    setExceptionHandler(new ClientExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleException(Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    setStreamEventDispatcher(streamEventDispatcher);
    connect(server, port, application, connectCallback);
}

private IEventDispatcher streamEventDispatcher = new IEventDispatcher() {
    public void dispatchEvent(IEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ClientStream.dispachEvent()" + event.toString());
    }
};

private IPendingServiceCallback methodCallCallback = new IPendingServiceCallback() {
    public void resultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call) {
        System.out.println("methodCallCallback");
        Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) call.getResult();
        System.out.printf("Response %s\n", map);
    }
};

public void getFlvList() {
    invoke("demoService.getListOfAvailableFLVs", new Object[] {}, methodCallCallback);
}

public void test() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                getFlvList();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private IPendingServiceCallback connectCallback = new IPendingServiceCallback() {
    public void resultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call) {
        System.out.println("connectCallback");
        ObjectMap<?, ?> map = (ObjectMap<?, ?>) call.getResult();
        String code = (String) map.get("code");
        System.out.printf("Response code: %s\n", code);
        if ("NetConnection.Connect.Rejected".equals(code)) {
            System.out.printf("Rejected: %s\n", map.get("description"));
            disconnect();
            synchronized (ClientTest.class) {
                finished = true;
                ClientTest.class.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if ("NetConnection.Connect.Success".equals(code)) {
            test();
            createStream(createStreamCallback);
        }           
    }
};

private IPendingServiceCallback createStreamCallback = new IPendingServiceCallback() {
    public void resultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call) {
        int streamId = (Integer) call.getResult();
        /*
         NetStream.play(name, start, length, reset)
         - start An optional numeric parameter that specifies the start time, in seconds. This parameter can also be used to indicate whether the stream is live or recorded.
            The default value for start is -2, which means that Flash Player first tries to play the live stream specified in name. If a live stream of that name is not found,
            Flash Player plays the recorded stream specified in name. If neither a live nor a recorded stream is found, Flash Player opens a live stream named name, even 
            though no one is publishing on it. When someone does begin publishing on that stream, Flash Player begins playing it.
            If you pass -1 for start, Flash Player plays only the live stream specified in name. If no live stream is found, Flash Player waits for it indefinitely 
            if len is set to -1; if len is set to a different value, Flash Player waits for len seconds before it begins playing the next item in the playlist.
            If you pass 0 or a positive number for start, Flash Player plays only a recorded stream named name, beginning start seconds from the beginning of the stream.
            If no recorded stream is found, Flash Player begins playing the next item in the playlist immediately.
            If you pass a negative number other than -1 or -2 for start, Flash Player interprets the value as if it were -2.

        - len An optional numeric parameter that specifies the duration of the playback, in seconds.
            The default value for len is -1, which means that Flash Player plays a live stream until it is no longer available or plays a recorded stream until it ends.
            If you pass 0 for len, Flash Player plays the single frame that is start seconds from the beginning of a recorded stream (assuming that start is equal to or greater than 0).
            If you pass a positive number for len, Flash Player plays a live stream for len seconds after it becomes available, or plays a recorded stream for len seconds.
            (If a stream ends before len seconds, playback ends when the stream ends.)
            If you pass a negative number other than -1 for len, Flash Player interprets the value as if it were -1.

        - reset An optional Boolean value or number that specifies whether to flush any previous playlist. If reset is false (0), name is added (queued) in the current playlist;
          that is, name plays only after previous streams finish playing. You can use this technique to create a dynamic playlist. If reset is true (1), any previous play calls 
          are cleared and name is played immediately. By default, the value is true.
            You can also specify a value of 2 or 3 for the reset parameter, which is useful when playing recorded stream files that contain message data. These values are analogous to 
            passing false (0) and true (1), respectively: a value of 2 maintains a playlist, and a value of 3 resets the playlist. However, the difference is that specifying 2 or 3 for 
            reset causes Flash Media Server to return all messages in the recorded stream file at once, rather than at the intervals at which the messages were originally recorded
            (the default behavior).
         */
        // live buffer 0.5s / vod buffer 4s
        if (live) {
            conn.ping(new Ping(Ping.CLIENT_BUFFER, streamId, 500));
            play(streamId, filename, -1, -1);
        } else {
            conn.ping(new Ping(Ping.CLIENT_BUFFER, streamId, 4000));
            play(streamId, filename, 0, -1);                
        }
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void onCommand(RTMPConnection conn, Channel channel, Header header, Notify notify) {
    super.onCommand(conn, channel, header, notify);
    System.out.println("onInvoke, header = " + header.toString());
    System.out.println("onInvoke, notify = " + notify.toString());
    Object obj = notify.getCall().getArguments().length > 0 ? notify.getCall().getArguments()[0] : null;
    if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
        String code = map.get("code");
        if (StatusCodes.NS_PLAY_STOP.equals(code)) {
            synchronized (ClientTest.class) {
                finished = true;
                ClientTest.class.notifyAll();
            }
            disconnect();
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
        }
    }

}

/**
 * @return the live
 */
public boolean isLive() {
    return live;
}

/**
 * @param live the live to set
 */
public void setLive(boolean live) {
    this.live = live;
}
```

}

First it showed me

> Keystore or password are null

Then I go to RTMPSClient.java to annotate this line
And then here is the log.

> 2016-01-08 15:42:10,368 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Set handler:
>   org.red5.client.ClientTest@ef9176 2016-01-08 15:42:10,374 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Set handler:
>   org.red5.client.ClientTest@ef9176 2016-01-08 15:42:10,377 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - setExceptionHandler:
>   org.red5.client.ClientTest$5@1ca901e 2016-01-08 15:42:10,377 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connect server:
>   myred5ServerName port 443 application RtmpRelay
>   connectCallback org.red5.client.ClientTest$3@49fd9b 2016-01-08
>   15:42:10,381 [DEBUG] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler -
>   connect server: myred5ServerName port 443 connect
>   - params: {app=RtmpRelay, tcUrl=rtmp://myred5ServerName:443/RtmpRelay,
>   audioCodecs=3575, path=RtmpRelay, capabilities=15, videoFunction=1,
>   swfUrl=null, flashVer=WIN 11,2,202,235, videoCodecs=252, pageUrl=null,
>   objectEncoding=0, fpad=false} callback:
>   org.red5.client.ClientTest$3@49fd9b args: null 2016-01-08 15:42:10,381
>   [INFO] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler -
>   rtmp://myred5ServerName:443/RtmpRelay 2016-01-08
>   15:42:10,795 [DEBUG] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler -
>   Session created 2016-01-08 15:42:10,850 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.BaseConnection - New BaseConnection - type: persistent
>   2016-01-08 15:42:10,851 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.BaseConnection -
>   Generated session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:10,867 [INFO]
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor -
>   Initializing ExecutorService  2016-01-08 15:42:10,868 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connections: 1 2016-01-08
>   15:42:10,868 [TRACE] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager -
>   Connection created: RTMPMinaConnection null:0 to null client: null
>   session: AHWDCE1GVSI4E state: connect 2016-01-08 15:42:10,868 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - setIoSession conn:
>   RTMPMinaConnection 54.249.13.195:443 to null client: null session:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E state: connect 2016-01-08 15:42:11,298 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Handshake ctor 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,386 [TRACE] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Setting
>   handshake type: 3 2016-01-08 15:42:11,678 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Adding the SSL Filter sslFilter
>   to the chain 2016-01-08 15:42:11,681 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client[1](no
>   sslEngine) Initializing the SSL Handler 2016-01-08 15:42:11,741
>   [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client[1](no
>   sslEngine) SSL Handler Initialization done. 2016-01-08 15:42:11,746
>   [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session
>   Client1 : Starting the first handshake 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,747 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the NEED_WRAP state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,749 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session
>   Client1: Writing Message : WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0
>   lim=200 cap=264: 16 03 03 00 C3 01 00 00 BF 03 03 56 8F 68 53 80...]
>   2016-01-08 15:42:11,752 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler
>   - Session Client1 processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,752 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session opened 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,753 [DEBUG] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler -
>   Handshake - client phase 1 2016-01-08 15:42:11,753 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - doHandshake: null 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,753 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake -
>   generateClientRequest1 2016-01-08 15:42:11,753 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Creating client handshake
>   part 1 with keys/hashes 2016-01-08 15:42:11,769 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Public key:
>   78668315212650400198827186223390359611077988560233147216455670641253464082043705461893836314852397223863719227558751209473569845879501294308958930567273504944711329557183892645652712976106317821813632735196388382068508141569520794069165208541632289296819978630098062466414991768903103649759385818784493305923
>   2016-01-08 15:42:11,780 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake
>   - Public key as bytes - length [128]: 700703a6d5388f6df4794834f384602d6112f7d2269393d79960e23209c0c78b900c13141b5e5accaa9101917f2743682d9f430048362a74df3593d79a1c64d6c791109d929fc780316ab156d7eebe8d61ef823143386fb9b3e73930612915501d5ac10b7a7ebbfa3987528f04a6a46130d4b72bb8b0368a6ca30b32b9818043
>   2016-01-08 15:42:11,780 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake
>   - Client public key: 700703a6d5388f6df4794834f384602d6112f7d2269393d79960e23209c0c78b900c13141b5e5accaa9101917f2743682d9f430048362a74df3593d79a1c64d6c791109d929fc780316ab156d7eebe8d61ef823143386fb9b3e73930612915501d5ac10b7a7ebbfa3987528f04a6a46130d4b72bb8b0368a6ca30b32b9818043
>   2016-01-08 15:42:11,781 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmpe.RTMPEIoFilter - Not encrypting write request
>   2016-01-08 15:42:11,782 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter -
>   Session Client1: Writing Message : WriteRequest:
>   HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=1537 cap=1537: 03 00 00 00 00 80 00 07 02 0F 55
>   92 23 09 84 C0...] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,941 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Message received : HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=2048 cap=2048: 16 03 03 00 59
>   02 00 00 55 03 03 CF DB 23 E6 48...] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,941 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   Processing the received message 2016-01-08 15:42:11,941 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,942 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_TASK state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,943 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,943 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Processing the SSL Data  2016-01-08 15:42:11,943 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Message received : HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=2048 cap=4096: 7D 64 12 DC 74
>   4A 34 A1 1D 0A EA 96 1D 0B 15 FC...] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,943 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   Processing the received message 2016-01-08 15:42:11,943 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,943 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Processing the SSL Data  2016-01-08 15:42:11,944 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Message received : HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=464 cap=4096: 20 0C 59 88 62
>   07 CE CE F7 4E F9 BB 59 A1 98 E5...] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,944 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   Processing the received message 2016-01-08 15:42:11,944 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,944 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_TASK state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,949 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,950 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_TASK state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,961 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,962 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_TASK state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,975 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_WRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,975 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Writing Message : WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=75 cap=132: 16 03
>   03 00 46 10 00 00 42 41 04 80 B7 B5 9F 24...] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,975
>   [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the NEED_WRAP state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,975 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session
>   Client1: Writing Message : WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0
>   lim=6 cap=8: 14 03 03 00 01 01] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,975 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   processing the NEED_WRAP state 2016-01-08 15:42:11,976 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Writing Message : WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=45 cap=66: 16 03
>   03 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 04 B3...] 2016-01-08 15:42:11,976
>   [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,976 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,976 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:11,976 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session
>   Client1: Processing the SSL Data  2016-01-08 15:42:12,135
>   [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session
>   Client1: Message received : HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=51
>   cap=4096: 14 03 03 00 01 01 16 03 03 00 28 29 B4 4C D8 BC...]
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,136 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler
>   - Session Client1 Processing the received message 2016-01-08 15:42:12,136 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the NEED_UNWRAP state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,137 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 processing the FINISHED state 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,137 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session
>   Client1 is now secured 2016-01-08 15:42:12,137 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Processing the SSL Data  2016-01-08 15:42:12,137 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1: Writing
>   Message : WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=1537 cap=1537: 03 00 00
>   00 00 80 00 07 02 0F 55 92 23 09 84 C0...] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,140
>   [DEBUG] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - messageSent
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,140 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,140 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Getting connection by
>   session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,298 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1: Message
>   received : HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=95 cap=2048: 17 03 03 00 5A 29 B4 4C
>   D8 BC 7E 9E AA DA 75 CC...] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,298 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   Processing the received message 2016-01-08 15:42:12,299 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Processing the SSL Data  2016-01-08 15:42:12,300 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmpe.RTMPEIoFilter - Session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,301 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Getting connection by
>   session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,301 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmpe.RTMPEIoFilter - Handshake exists on the
>   session 2016-01-08 15:42:12,301 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmpe.RTMPEIoFilter - Not decrypting message
>   received: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=66 cap=95: 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20
>   34 30 30 20 42 41 44...] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,302 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter - Processing a
>   MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 1 2016-01-08 15:42:12,304 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder - Session id:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,304 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Getting connection by
>   session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,310 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: AHWDCE1GVSI4E with thread:
>   NioProcessor-2 2016-01-08 15:42:12,310 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Caller:
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler$RTMPMinaCodecFactory$1.decode
>
> ## 256 2016-01-08 15:42:12,310 [TRACE] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder - Decoder lock
>
> acquiring.. AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,310 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder - Decoder lock
>   acquired AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,311 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Decoding for
>   connection - session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,312 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - RTMPDecodeState
>   [sessionId=AHWDCE1GVSI4E, decoderState=0, decoderBufferAmount=0]
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,312 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Can start
>   decoding 2016-01-08 15:42:12,312 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Decoding for
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,312 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder -
>   decodeServerHandshake - buffer: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=66 cap=1536: 48
>   54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 34 30 30 20 42 41 44...] 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,312 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Handshake init
>   too small, buffering. remaining: 66 2016-01-08 15:42:12,312 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Decoding finished
>   for AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,312 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Cannot continue
>   decoding 2016-01-08 15:42:12,313 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder - Decoder lock
>   releasing.. AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,313 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: null with thread:
>   NioProcessor-2 2016-01-08 15:42:12,313 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Caller:
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler$RTMPMinaCodecFactory$1.decode
>
> ## 275 2016-01-08 15:42:12,313 [DEBUG] org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1: Message
>
> received : HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=31 cap=2048: 15 03 03 00 1A 29 B4 4C
>   D8 BC 7E 9E AB 2E 99 50...] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,313 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Session Client1
>   Processing the received message 2016-01-08 15:42:12,314 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client1:
>   Processing the SSL Data  2016-01-08 15:42:12,314 [DEBUG]
>   org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter - Session Client[1]: Writing
>   Message : WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=31 cap=33: 15 03 03 00 1A
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 AD DD 15...] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,470 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session closed 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,470 [TRACE] org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler -
>   Session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,471 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Getting connection by
>   session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,471 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connectionClosed
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,471 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,471 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - close: AHWDCE1GVSI4E
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,472 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - State: connect 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,472 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E with thread: NioProcessor-2 2016-01-08 15:42:12,472
>   [DEBUG] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Caller:
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection.close #924 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,479 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Stream
>   service was not found for scope: null or non-existant 2016-01-08
>   15:42:12,479 [DEBUG] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - Close, not
>   connected nothing to do 2016-01-08 15:42:12,479 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Memory at close - free:
>   1596K total: 15872K 2016-01-08 15:42:12,479 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - IO Session closing: true
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,479 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection state: RTMP
>   [state=disconnecting, encrypted=false, readChunkSize=128,
>   writeChunkSize=128, encoding=AMF0] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,480 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.client.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connectionClosed
>   2016-01-08 15:42:12,480 [DEBUG]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,480 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - setStateCode: 5 -
>   disconnected 2016-01-08 15:42:12,486 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connection manager instance
>   does not exist 2016-01-08 15:42:12,486 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connection manager bean
>   doesnt exist, creating new instance 2016-01-08 15:42:12,490 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Removing connection with
>   session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,491 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connections (0) at
>   pre-remove: [] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,492 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed:
>   RTMPMinaConnection 54.249.13.195:443 to null client: null session:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E state: disconnected 2016-01-08 15:42:12,558 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - setStateCode: 5 -
>   disconnected 2016-01-08 15:42:12,558 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Removing connection with
>   session id: AHWDCE1GVSI4E 2016-01-08 15:42:12,558 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connections (0) at
>   pre-remove: [] 2016-01-08 15:42:12,558 [TRACE]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed:
>   RTMPMinaConnection 54.249.13.195:443 to null client: null session:
>   AHWDCE1GVSI4E state: disconnected

I wish someone could tell me where I was wrong.THKS.

Comment: RTMPS is broken right now; I'm working on it.

Comment: You guys are great,thanks.And I switch it to RTMPT, and it goes OK. Another question is that I prepared to create a threadpool, and every thread in this pool instantiates a red5RTMPT client to do press test, I don't sure whether the method is OK, cause I have tried the flazr tool,but connected failed. Wish you can give me some suggestion. :-)